# Hook Up Function To Delegate in Dll

Tags: c#, dll

main.cs:

```
static string str;
static int i;
static void DoingSomething(string parameter1,int parameter2)
{
str=parameter1;
i=parameter2;
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
Assembly a=Assembly.LoadFile(@"path\To\file1.dll");
}
```

file1.dll (source code):

```
namespace file1
{
    public class FileClass : FileClassBasic 
    {
        void FileClassBasic.Do() {
            API.functions.DoSomething("",5);
        }
    }
}
```

file2.dll (source code):

```
namespace file2
{
    public interface FileClassBasic 
    {
        void Do();
    }

    public static class API
    {
        public class Functions
        {
        public delegate string DoSomethingFunction(string p1, int p2);
            public DoSomethingFunction DoSomething;
        }
        public static Functions functions;

    }

}
```

How to hook up function DoingSomething() from Main.cs to delegate API.Functions.DoSomethingFunction in file2.dll, so class in file1.dll will be able to use it?

Comment: What dll is `main.cs` in?

Comment: Instead of `Assembly.LoadFile` [add a project reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019) to "file1.dll".

Comment: @ckuri I need to load that dll in runtime, because location of loaded dll will not always be the same. I can add reference to file2.dll if this somehow helps me solve this problem.